# How to set "Text direction" to RTL in StaticView

Tags: android, right-to-left, staticlayout

I am using a StaticLayout and using some RTL text.
The problem is that it's not handling RTL well. In `TextView` you can set a "textDirection". is there any way to do it here too?
Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't work on all versions or just on old?

Comment: It doesn't work on all versions.

Comment: @ssgr The proper tag replacement for 'rtl' is 'right-to-left'. Fixed it already :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the left-to-right mark in the string:

```
left-to-right mark: &lrm; or &#x200e; (U+200E)
right-to-left mark: &rlm; or &#x200f; (U+200F)
```

So in your string try usןמע in the following way

```
String rtl = "\u200F ימין לשמאל";
```

Comment: The text can be both RTL and LTR... So, should I add at runtime "\u200F"?
It doesn't feel right.

Comment: Have you tried 
yourTextCiew.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);

Comment: It's not a textView... Its a StaticLayout.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, it solved by changing

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

to

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

in TextView tag.

I hope this help.

Comment: As you can see, I use, and have to use, a staticLayout. not a TextView. So it's not relevant.